# I get the error "./en_US.UTF-8: No such file or directory" when starting nvi

Tags: startup, nvi

I'm using **nvi** on Mac OS X 10.10.3, installed from MacPorts.

Whenever I start the editor, the following message is displayed in my console:

```
./en_US.UTF-8: No such file or directory
```

I'm just curious as to what it tries to do. `en_US.UTF-8` happens to be my locale setting:

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an *old* but [known problem on OS X](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/25733).

This issue has [a patch](https://trac.macports.org/attachment/ticket/25733/nvilangmsg.patch), which is unfortunately not yet incorporated. You can apply it manually to fix your `nvi` build.